# Naming convention for properties in property file

Tags: java, naming-conventions

What are the naming conventions for property names defined in properties files in Java? Can I use uppercase or only lowercase?

For example: bankAccountNumber or bank.account.number?

Is it defined somewhere on the internet?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Naming convention is recommended  as lowercase in property file.
`bank.account.number` this is more appreciable.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder even there is no standardized way to do this, it does follow minimal OOP concepts. A bank will have an account which will have a number. He could then do: `bank.account.owner.name`. This type of format makes it easy to parse, so creating instances from these files is very efficient.

Comment: Only think I can see the readbility which could enhance maintainability

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder OP asked about *convention* and not *standardization*.

Answer (score 15):

As per my understanding, there is no any standard rule written for `.properties` file in `java.` 
but if you see the `.properties` files inside the `lib` folder of `Java\jre` most of them have lower cased `.properties` file names. And the `properties` themselves are also lower cased.
**such as**:

```
psfontj2d.properties
```

**key values**

```
courier_new=courier
courier_new_bold=courier_bold
```

Comment: The maintained file having various types of formats like avantgarde=avantgarde_book, itcbookman_light=bookman_light,newcenturyschoolbook=newcenturyschoolbook,serif.latin1.plain=Times-Roman,font.0=AvantGarde-Book ISOF what is standard then?

Answer (score 9):

**Kebab case is recommended**

According to the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding) (see notes in the table with `relaxed binding`) kebab case is recommended for use in .properties and .yml files.

Answer (score 5):

There's no particular standard for naming properties, but convention appears to be of the form

```
a.b.c.d = x
```

in lowercase. I would expect some sort of informal hierarchy e.g.

```
bank.
bank.account.
bank.account.name.
bank.account.pin.
```

etc.

If it's a property which directly affects a particular class I may name it after that class (or at least use the package name). However that is also an example of implementation leak, and I'd think seriously before doing that.

Answer (score 2):

In JSF you can see in ValidationMessages.properties something

```
javax.validation.constraints.Pattern.message
```

or in JsfMessages.properties

```
javax.faces.component.UISelectOne.INVALID
```

So you can use wherever you like, i like just lowercase, package formatted

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no such common conventions for property files. However, using lowercase letters in an **eligible/easy-to-understand** format (e.g. **bank.account.number**) sounds good, and using the property files with their original extensions (**.properties**) is also recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Resource Bundle accepts only fully qualified base name of the bundle, with no file extension. In this case it will try to load the bundle of files like this

**messages/EN/properties.properties**

I am sure you intend something different than the conventional internationalization, but convention would have been **"messages_en.properties"** (en when language, EN when country)

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard convention for naming properties in property file.

**Ref:**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

As you are Java user, you can use **camelCase**.

*For the given example, the name can be **bankAccountNumber**.*

In case, if the requirement is to follow the hierarchy structure, dots can be used as below.

- *bank*
- *bank.account.name*
- *bank.account.number*
- *bank.department.name*