# Spring @Value doesn't work in nested configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, spring-properties

I have a application.properties:

```
app.cert.identity.subject.organizationalUnit=test
app.cert.identity.subject.O=Pacific College
app.cert.identity.subject.L=CanTho
app.cert.identity.subject.ST=CanTho
app.cert.identity.subject.C=VN
```

My class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.cert.identity")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Data
public class IdentityCertificateDefinition {

    private Subject subject;

    @Data
    @Configuration
    public static class Subject {

        private String organizationalUnit;    //Does work

        @Value("${app.cert.identity.subject.O}")    //Does NOT work
        private String organization;

        @Value("${app.cert.identity.subject.L}")    //Does NOT work
        private String location;

        @Value("${app.cert.identity.subject.ST}")    //Does NOT work
        private String state;

        @Value("${app.cert.identity.subject.C}")    //Does NOT work
        private String countryCode;

        @Value("${app.cert.identity.validity.not-after-in-days}")    //Does NOT work
        private int notAfterInDays;

    }

}
```

And here is the result:
[image]
You guys can see just the organizationalUnit work, the rest doesn't work (all are null). I do not know how to make the rest properties work. I would like to keep application.properties.

Comment: I think the `application.properties` file have some conflicts with `SPACE` and `_` `underscore` So we cannot add them in properties file. So please try to remove it

Comment: or for testing try on thing `app.cert.identity.subject.O=Pacific College` move this from second position to last position. You will observe all the properies values are accessable but not the last one

Comment: Hi, I think it's not a problem. I just need to change the properties name to match with the fields in java code and it works, but I don't prefer that way. I want to keep property file

Comment: is the problem resolved ??

Comment: The problem should be solved easily by @Milgo's comment, or I just need to rename the properties to match with the java fields, but both solutions here are not my expectation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12473563/5108695 have a look

Comment: BTW its not important that `application.properties` `keys` should not match with the Java `variables` I mean it's not mendatory

Comment: Yes I know it doesn't need to be matched. And this question is about how to make it work WITHOUT renaming the properties key

Comment: Could you please, rename `keys` to all lower case once and try!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224664/discussion-between-sot-and-dupinder-singh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the static class configuration with this code:

```
@Configuration
@Data
public class IdentityCertificateDefinition {

    @Autowired
    private Subject subject;

    @Data
    @Configuration
    public static class Subject {

        private String organizationalUnit;

        @Value("${app.cert.identity.subject.O}")
        private String organization;

        @Value("${app.cert.identity.subject.L}")
        private String location;

        @Value("${app.cert.identity.subject.ST}")
        private String state;

        @Value("${app.cert.identity.subject.C}")
        private String countryCode;

        @Value("${app.cert.identity.validity.not-after-in-days}")
        private int notAfterInDays;
    }
}
```

If you don't need to use a static class in a configuration class, just use:

```
@Configuration
@Data
public class IdentityCertificateDefinition {

    @Value("${app.cert.identity.subject.OU}")
    private String organizationalUnit;

    @Value("${app.cert.identity.subject.O}")
    private String organization;

    @Value("${app.cert.identity.subject.L}")
    private String location;

    @Value("${app.cert.identity.subject.ST}")
    private String state;

    @Value("${app.cert.identity.subject.C}")
    private String countryCode;

    @Value("${app.cert.identity.validity.not-after-in-days}")
    private int notAfterInDays;
}
```

Comment: Yes, since I have a lot of properties between identity and subject. I just did not put the code here (to make the content shorter)

Comment: It's a bit clunky and I'd definitely prefer the second configuration but it's a valid configuration. Since there is no 'official' way, you can use it if you prefer/need it this way.

Answer (score 2):

The problem should be related to

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.cert.identity")
```

Mainly you're say the properties have a common prefix, but then when you inject their values your putting the prefix again:

```
 @Value("${app.cert.identity.subject.L}")
```

So Spring is acting to find a property named (prefix + class + value of @Value):

```
 @Value("${app.cert.identity.subject.app.cert.identity.subject.L}")
```

Change

```
@Value("${app.cert.identity.subject.L}")
```

To

```
@Value("${L}")
```

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'identityCertificateDefinition.Subject': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'O' in value "${O}"